# Angular - if statement to checking current route

Tags: angular, if-statement, angular-router

I have modal component . l  want to check if user he is come form `'/tabs/tab1'` or `'/tabs/tab2'` to display data specific data depending on current url coming form . The problem is the data are displaying both of them in modal component html  , they are not  listen to if statement below .

code :

```
    page1:boolean= false
   page2:boolean= false

  constructor(private router:Router) { 


     if (this.router.url === '/tabs/tab1') {
            this.page1= true
            this.page2= false
            this.getData()

        } else if (this.router.url === '/tabs/tab2'){
          this.page1= false 
          this.page2= true

          this.getData()

        }
}
```

html

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="page1; else page1">
   // check if page 1 route /tabs/tab1' display data page1 and hide data 
      page 2
  // for page 1 different data   
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #page1>

  </ng-template>

  <ng-container *ngIf="page2; else page2">
   // check if page2 route /tabs/tab2' display data page 2 and hide 
       data page 1

    // Also of paga 2 different data 
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #page2>

  </ng-template>
```

Comment: Could you expand on *"doesn't work correctly"*? Give a [mcve].

Comment: You should log what happens in you constructor (this.router.url ?). Also you have 2 `#elseTemplate` in your template, which is not allowed...

Comment: @jonrsharpe . i have both data display for page 1 and page 2 . he doesn't listen to if statement

Comment: @Random l got current url in console log .

Comment: So one of the `if` is true ? Are you sure about that ?

Comment: @Random Yes if user coming form ` /tabs/tab1'` display data page1 and hide data 
      page 2 if user coming from ` /tabs/tab2'` display data page 2 and hide 
       data page 1 .

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: @Random the problem is i have the data for page 1 and page 2 are display , i want display only one of them ending on url route page above .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions are not working as you want

Try this below condition

```
<ng-container *ngIf="page1 && !page2">
  // Your data to show here    
 </ng-container>


<ng-container *ngIf="page2 && !page1">
  // Your data to show here 
</ng-container>
```

This way if the page1 is false and page2 is true then only it will display the page2 and if page1 is true and page2 is galse then it will display that container page1

If your want to show page1 and page2 both some time then you can manually set it true and false and only set if true page1 then display it and if true page2 then display it like this below

```
<ng-container *ngIf="page1">
  // Your data to show here    
 </ng-container>


<ng-container *ngIf="page2">
  // Your data to show here 
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems is that you have two template variables `#page1, #page2` and two component variables `page1, page2` with the same names page1 and page2. So when you say `*ngIf="page1; else page1"` and `*ngIf="page2; else page2"` those ifs are looking to your template variables on `#page1` and `#page2` which are objects hence truty values and are always evaluated as true. You must rename your template variables or component variables in order to use the correct ones. One solution could be changing your template like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="page1; else page1ref">
   // check if page 1 route /tabs/tab1' display data page1 and hide data 
      page 2
  // for page 1 different data   
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #page1ref>

  </ng-template>

  <ng-container *ngIf="page2; else page2ref">
   // check if page2 route /tabs/tab2' display data page 2 and hide 
       data page 1

    // Also of paga 2 different data 
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #page2ref>

  </ng-template>
```